# While using startx I get the response 'Error locking authority file'

Tags: raspbian

While starting startx, I get error

1. fatal error could not create lock file in /tmp/.tx0-lock
2. error in locking authority file.
3. Even I am unable to delete .Xauthority file

Comment: can you paste your disk usage output 'df -h' command?

Comment: May be a permissions problem. Try deleting as root.

Answer (score 3):

After a simple Google search, I found [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=36114). Take a look at the 2nd and 3rd comment for a possible solution.

According to @**KnotMan33**

> Thank YOU my pi is now working!!
>
> I didn't do anything but check my SD
>   card usage with
>
> ```
>     df -h
> ```
>
> and then it ran Startx again and i worked!
>
> I think that the Pi didn't
>   recognize that there was space available until i ran `df -h` where it
>   realized there was lots of extra space.
>
> Thank you again!!!

Comment: would be more appropriate to include some quotes from the post just in case if the forum goes offline and renders your answer irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

Run the command:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select 'Expand Filesystem'

Select 'Enable Boot to Desktop'

Select Finish, then reboot